# How to use linebreak in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I am new to python Django.
I want new line in specific places, So I tried

```
def abc(request):
    text = "This is\n a good example"
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'text' : text})
```

In HTML part

```
Hello {{ text|linebreaks }}
```

And this is working perfectly fine with output

Hello This is

a good example

Here is my question
I store some 400 - 800 words in my database which has approximately 4-5 paragraph.
I want to new line here.

So, I store data like "This is\n a good example" in my database.

And simply call it in django template(Html side)

but it prints
    Hello This is\n a good example

In here why line break is not working?

My HTML true code

```
{% for essay in eassays %}
{{ essay.description|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have changed name. Also, I am loading 100 such data.
Any possible solution or other logic!

Thankyou!

Comment: Because you stored `'\\n'` (or a backslash and an `n`), not a new line character (`\n`, or in hex `\x10`). Note that if you write `\n` in a form. Then it is escaped. You better use a `<textarea>` and thus use multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I store data like "This is\n a good example" in my database.

You likely stored `'\\n'` in the database, so a backslash, followed by an `n`. Not a [new line chacter `'\n'` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages). Note that if you write `\n` in a form element, then it will be *escaped* and thus stored accordingly.

It might be better to use a `<textarea>` in your form elements to let users use new lines (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

You can try to fix the damage by substituting the strings, with:

```
from django.db.models import Replace, Value

Essay.objects.update(
    description=Replace('description', Value('\\n'), Value('\n'))
)
```

and thus update your database such that `'\\n'` is now replaced by `'\n'`.